# Jenkins collapse pending jobs in build queue

Tags: jenkins

I would like to have multiple pending jobs collapsed into only 1 pending job.

For example, if two users "Build with Parameters" while the executors are busy, the same project then only one job should be created.  Similar to how the source control plugins catch up to the head, multiple commits get rolled into one job.

Bonus points if we can not collapse the jobs if the parameters differ.

Any ideas?

I am thinking of wrapping the job, with something like do_project that performs the work, and the project users interacts with would examine do_project's queue and determine if a new job should be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is to actually abort all previous builds and run only the latest build when there are multiple builds in the queue.
There is already a nice option called [disableConcurrentBuilds](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options) which disallow concurrent executions of the Pipeline, and since version [2.42](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-job-plugin/releases/tag/workflow-job-2.42) of the Pipeline: Job plugin, a new parameter was added
to this function called `abortPrevious` - which allows (when set to `true`)  to abort all the running builds and start the new build.

Usage in declarative pipeline:

```groovy
pipeline {
    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: true)
    }

   [...]
}
```

Usage in scripted pipeline:

```groovy
node {
    properties([disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: true)])

    [...]
}
```

This configuration will help you achieve your goal - every time a new build starts , and there are multiple builds running it will cancel all previous ones.
You can also use a parameter for this config `disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: params.ABORT_PREVIOUS)` but it will still prevent concurrent executions if passed as `false`.